# Different methods of class instance initialization and how to find if the given object is an instance of particular class

Tags: lua

I'm writing a module to generate some kind of encrypted access tokens. The encryption library I'm going to use ([`lua-resty-string.aes`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-string/blob/master/lib/resty/aes.lua)) uses the following method of class and class instance initialization:

```lua
local _M = { _VERSION = '0.14' } 
local mt = { __index = _M } 
function _M.new(...)
    ... 
    return setmetatable({ ... }, mt) 
end
```

What is the fundamental difference of this initialization method with the following one (I'm more familiar with)?

```lua
Class = {} 
Class.__index = Class 
function Class.new()
    return setmetatable({}, Class)
end
```

When I need to check is the variable passed to my function is an instance of the required class, for the second case I can use the following:

```lua
if getmetatable(obj) == Class then ...
```

However this is not working for the first case of initialization. I found the following works correctly:

```lua
local aes = require("resty.aes")
if (getmetatable(obj) or {}).__index == aes then ...
```

But I'm not sure is it OK or is there something more convenient to do it right? And what are the benefits of using the first method of class instance initialization?

Comment: I can find a disadvantage of using the second method: each instance is able to modify its class definition directly `obj.__index.foo = bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Metatable-based classes

First of all, `_M` is just a naming convention for a module "namespace". You could name it "module" or "Class" as in your second example.The only real difference is the separation of metatable and "methodtable" / "class" table:

```lua
local Class = {}
local metatable = { __index = Class } 
function Class.new(...)
    ... 
    return setmetatable({ ... }, metatable) 
end
```

cleanly separates the two; the metatable is a local variable and thus kept "private" to the class (if the `__metatable` field is set, it can further be hidden from `getmetatable`). If the metatable should be exposed for convenient checks, one way to go would be a `metatable` field in the `Class` table:

```lua
Class.metatable = metatable
```

the other pattern just mushes the metatable and methodtable in the same table. Lua's metamethod naming using a double underscore as prefix (e.g. `__index`) is designed to allow this:

```lua
local Class = {}
Class.__index = Class
function Class.new(...)
    ... 
    return setmetatable({ ... }, metatable) 
end
```

it requires a circular reference in the `Class` table (`Class.__index`); the metatable can be accessed from anywhere as long as the `Class` table is available because it *is* the metatable. Downsides of this include (1) potentially worse performance (due to hash collisions, because your metatable contains both the methods *and* the metamethods) and (2) somewhat dirty: If I inspected your `Class` table, it won't be neatly separated in metamethods and class methods; I'd have to separate it myself based on method naming.

It also means that indexing instances or the `Class` table allows "seeing" the underlying implementation which should probably be abstracted away / only accessible through indexing / using the operators / calling: `Class.__index` and `instance.__index` will be `Class`.

## Instance checking

Now to the problem of checking whether an object is an instance of a `Class`: If the second approach is used, comparing the return value of `getmetatable` works:

```lua
if getmetatable(obj) == Class then
    -- object is an instance of the class
end
```

if the metatable is exposed as `Class.metatable` or the like (may remind you of `Object.prototype` in JS), this works very similarly:

```lua
if getmetatable(obj) == Class.metatable then
    -- object is an instance of the class
end
```

alternatively, the `Class` may implement it's own `isinstance` method that checks against the "private" (local) metatable:

```lua
function Class.isinstance(table)
    return getmetatable(table) == metatable
end
```

a third alternative to allow the simply comparison against `Class` would be to set the `__metatable` field to `Class`:

```lua
local metatable = {__index = Class, __metatable = Class}
```

that way, the `metatable` is neatly `local`ized and separated from the `Class`, yet from the outside it seems as if the "mushy" pattern was used.

If the metatable is however not exposed and no `isinstance` method is available, you may have to resort to hacks such as the one you have shown to implement this:

```lua
if getmetatable(obj).__index == Class then
    -- object is an instance of the class
end
```

this doees however **rely on `__index` being used in a specific way** - a hidden implementation detail - and should, if possible, not be used in practice. Suppose `__index` is changed to an actual metamethod to log a warning because a field has been deprecated:

```lua
function metatable.__index(self, field)
    if field == "deprecated_field" then warn"deprecated_field is deprecated, use field instead!"
    return Class[field]
end
```

and suddenly your check breaks because the assumption that `metatable.__index == Class` simply doesn't hold anymore. An alternative hack to consider would be obtaining a metatable from an instance:

```lua
local instance = Class(...)
local class_metatable = getmetatable(instance)
...
if getmetatable(obj) == class_metatable then
    -- object is probably an instance of the class
end
```

Comment: A very comprehensive explanation, thanks!